# create several /dev/xconsole files

Tags: logs, console, devices

I am using `/dev/xconsole` to send system logs from `rsyslog`. That works great, because I am don't have to store the logs on disk.

I would like to have another similar file , i.e `/dev/xconsole1` where I can send other kind of logs.

How can I create such special file?

When I go to `/dev` and `ls` it does not show complete major/minor number:

```
prw-r----- 1 root adm           0  2014-Oct-11  13:12:02  xconsole
```

it only shows `0`. In contrast, other special files have both.

```
brw-rw---T 1 root disk     8,   1  2014-Oct-08  03:42:35  sda1
```

I know how to create special files using `mknod`, but to do that, I need the major/minor number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not every file under `/dev` is a device file that has major/minor numbers.

#### Example

```
$ ls -l |grep initctl
prw-------. 1 root root             0 Sep 17 13:27 initctl

$ stat initctl 
  File: ‘initctl’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   fifo
Device: 5h/5d   Inode: 8882        Links: 1
Access: (0600/prw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: system_u:object_r:initctl_t:s0
Access: 2014-09-17 13:27:12.140761620 -0400
Modify: 2014-09-17 13:27:12.140761620 -0400
Change: 2014-09-17 13:27:12.140761620 -0400
 Birth: -
```

Files with a `p......` in their permissions bits are named pipes, and are created using `mkfifo`.

#### References

- [Wikipedia - Unix File Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types)

Comment: on my system, `/dev/xconsole` gets created automatically. How can I find out who creates it? And in case I need a second file (`/dev/xconsole2`), how can I make it to be created automatically as well?

Comment: @MartinVegter - It's likely being created by udev. I'd ask it as a new Q though.

Comment: I have asked [a new question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168215/create-several-dev-xconsole-files-automatically-upon-boot) as you suggested