# create several /dev/xconsole files automatically upon boot

Tags: console, devices, udev, fifo

I understand from my [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160543/create-several-dev-xconsole-files/160555?noredirect=1#comment276722_160555) that the `/dev/xconsole` file can be created using `mkfifo`.

On my system (Debian Wheezy), `/dev/xconsole` gets created automatically. I am wondering who creates it (udev ?) and how I can configure that a second file gets created automatically, i.e. `/dev/xconsole2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Debian typically the selected `syslogd` package takes care of creating the `/dev/xconsole` pipe. You probably have `rsyslog` installed; look at the `/etc/init.d/rsyslog` script and search for `create_xconsole` which is the shell function that creates `/dev/xconsole`; it's trivial to modify that to create a second file.

Comment: that works perfectly